# Stop IntelliJ from rewriting my code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to stop rewriting my code to match its preferences?  I'm especially concerned with this when it comes to code that has already been committed to source control.  For example, the following line was mysteriously changed to the second example because IntelliJ preferred the latter spacing.

```
    assertLess((new Date().getTime()/1000)-8,attrs.mtime);
    assertLess((new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 8, attrs.mtime);
```

I don't want this to happen.  Any ideas?

Comment: And you didn't hit ctrl-alt-L ? Weird, that doesn't happen for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to uncheck this:

[image]

Comment: This is not occurring when I go to commit.  It is simply occurring while I am working in general.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in IDE Settings -> Editor -> Smart Keys named `Reformat on Paste:`

Check it is set to anything other than `Reformat Block`, for example `Indent Each Line`.